# Table filtering with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have some data stored in a table I would like to filter using Javascript. I type my filter string in an input field and show only rows which match.
But now, I would like to do this : for example, if I type `value1|value2` in my filter field, I want only rows which match with these 2 strings (`value1 AND value2`). I've tried many ways to do it but no one does exactly what I want ...

Here is an example of what I use to filter (works with one string) :

```
function filterFromName(text) {

    // Variables
    var filter, tableData, tr, td, i;
    filter = text.toUpperCase();
    tableData = document.getElementById('data_values');
    tr = tableData.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    // For each table row, hide those who don't match the search text
    for (i = 0; i< tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1]; // query the Alias column
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            else
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }        
    }

}
```

Is there a way to adapt this piece of code to do what I want?

Comment: why not use https://datatables.net/ ?

Comment: So, you want to parse your input string to create a query that would match your data? And you want to use `|` as the and (opposed to using `+` as `|` is rather an or)

Comment: I just wanted to use my own code and not a JQuery plugin ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now, I would like to do this : for example, if I type
>   "value1|value2" in my filter field, I want only rows which match with
>   these 2 strings (value1 AND value2).

You need to change your logic as (*comments inline*)

```
function filterFromName(text) {
    var tableData, tr, td, i;
    var filterParams = text.toUpperCase().split( "|" ); //split by | to get array of search parameters
    tableData = document.getElementById('data_values');
    tr = tableData.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    // For each table row, hide those who don't match the search text
    for (i = 0; i< tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1]; // query the Alias column
        if (td) {
            var tdValue = td.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
            var isMatched = filterParams.filter( function( val ){ return tdValue.indexOf( val ) > -1 }); //check if any val in filterParam array is matching the tdValue
            if ( isMatched.length ) //check length of filtered resultset
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            else
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for ;-)

Comment: @Kementari In that case, kindly accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.